# Azure DevOps "Code Coverage" view changes after pipeline run finished

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I do use `PublishCodeCoverageResults@2` task in my Azure DevOps pipeline

```yaml
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'JaCoCo'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/**/jacoco.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/'
    pathToSources: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/src/main/java/'
    failIfCoverageEmpty: false
```

Everything works nicely but the odd thing is - while running this task the Code Coverage shows me the Jacoco html reports, view looks like this

[image: Code Coverage view while pipeline task is running]

and here the Code Coverage View after the pipeline finished

[image: Code Coverage View after pipeline task finished]

The second view is not useful, cause you can't navigate into the class and see the code, while with the jacoco html reports this is possible.

[image: Drilldown to Classes]

What am I doing wrong? Or why is the view changing? How can I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possible things that might be wrong.

1. There are two versions of this task available with slightly different syntax. You're using inputs (`codeCoverageTool`, `reportDirectory`) that aren't available in version 2. These "illegal" properties are ignored at runtime and have no effect.

   The syntax between versions:

   - [`PublishCodeCoverageResults@1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-code-coverage-results-v1?view=azure-pipelines)

     ```yaml
     - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
       inputs:
         codeCoverageTool: # string. Required. 'Cobertura' | 'JaCoCo'
         summaryFileLocation: # string. Required. Summary file
         pathToSources: # string. Path to source files.
         reportDirectory: # string. Report directory.
         additionalCodeCoverageFiles: # string. Additional files.
         failIfCoverageEmpty: # boolean
     ```
   - [`PublishCodeCoverageResults@2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-code-coverage-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines)

     ```yaml
     - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
       inputs:
         summaryFileLocation: # string. Required. Path to summary files.
         pathToSources: # string. Path to Source files
         failIfCoverageEmpty: # boolean
     ```
2. Both the v1 and v2 documentation states that the `pathToSources` must be an absolute path:

   > Specifying a path to source files is required when coverage XML reports don't contain an absolute path to source files. For example, JaCoCo reports don't use absolute paths, so when publishing JaCoCo coverage for Java apps, the pattern is similar to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyApp/src/main/java/`. This input should point to an absolute path to source files on the host. For example, `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyApp/`.

Remove the wildcards `**` in your `pathToSources` to ensure the report is properly generated. The variable `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` represents an absolute path to the root of your repository.

Comment: Thanks very much. I do get following error "No source directories supplied for 'JaCoCo' coverage file" and "File 'Adapter1.java' does not exist (any more).". 
But the reason why I do have wildcards ( '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/src/main/java/' 
) is cause I do have a multi-module project and different src-folders, meaning under $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) there are module1/src/main/java and module2/src/main/java etc.. Now I try with a string of paths separated by semicolon:

Comment: --> pathToSources: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/module1/src/main/java/;$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/module2/src/main/java/ '

Comment: It worked with above pathToSources. Happy happy happy! Thanks very much!!

Answer (score -1):

```yaml
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'JaCoCo'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/**/jacoco.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/'
    pathToSources: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/src/main/java/'
    failIfCoverageEmpty: false
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this didn't help.